# Force scipy.optimize.curve_fit() to return last determined parameters of failed fit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I need to preform a large number of fits for a blocking analysis. The problem is, that this blocking yields very scattered ("bad") data for some of the regressions. This cannot be fixed, since the data is correlated energy values from an MD simulation and seems to be a natural result, if the results of my fellow students are anything to go by.

I tried to get around the `RuntimeError` that `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()` throws, by using a `try` catch. I thought that maybe the result of each iteration of the curve fitting will be saved in my `popt` variable, which stores the optimal parameters of my function. That way, even if I get the `RuntimeError`, I still get the last parameters and my iteration over 150 fits or so won't crash.

However, this isn't the case. Instead of getting a `RuntimeError`, I get an `UnboundLocalError`, because I'm trying to reference popt when defining two new variables `a,b` after the try catch.  So I wanted to ask how I can force `curve_fit()` to give me it's fitted parameters, even if it thinks they are incorrect.

Here's a code snippet with which I examined the problem:

```py
def G_sol(df):
    for index,lam in enumerate(df.columns):
        List = list(df.loc[:,lam])
        List = [np.float64(l) for l in List]

        # iterate over blocks.
        y, x = np.array([(ineff, segm) for ineff, segm in blocks(List)]).transpose()

        # Not all regressions will work due to bad data.
        # This prevents the loop from crashing and returns
        # the last result of the optimization.
        try:
            print('lol')
            popt, popt_cov = optimize.curve_fit(fit, x, y, method='lm')
            print(popt)
        except RuntimeError:
            pass

        a,b = popt[0],popt[1]
```

The `print('lol')` is still executed, but the `print(popt)` isn't. I guess that means that it already went to the except block. Apparently `popt` is not defined if it fails in the try catch, so `a,b` cannot be defined by it.

Full traceback, if you're interested:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-3449f530a001>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/local/ego/GsolveSideChains/blocking.py', wdir='/local/nelle/GsolveSideChains')

  File "/usr/local/linux/shared_soft/python/python3.6/anaconda5.1.0_ML/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/local/linux/shared_soft/python/python3.6/anaconda5.1.0_ML/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/local/ego/GsolveSideChains/blocking.py", line 225, in <module>
    G_solv = G_sol(Paths)

  File "/local/ego/GsolveSideChains/blocking.py", line 190, in G_sol
    a,b = parms[0],parms[1]

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'parms' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: I changed the name of parms to popt for the post, because I thorugh it would be more familiar for people using scipy. Forgot to do it for the traceback though. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to set `a, b = np.nan, np.nan` before the try-except block and move `a, b = popt` unpacking into the try clause.
This way, you can deal with failed fits (i.e. nans) later on.